# Symfony, Docker container fpm, apache : could not find driver [doctrine:database:create]

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I'm trying to create symfony 5.4 project using docker with a container for apache, php fpm, symfony, mysql db.
but actualy i don't succed to create my database, i get this error:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 128:
                                                          
  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver  
                                                          

In Exception.php line 18:
                         
  could not find driver  
                         

In PDOConnection.php line 40:
                         
  could not find driver
```

this doctrine conf : config/packages/doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        
        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

this is extensions activated :

```
;extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
;extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

;extension=soap
extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xmlrpc
```

this my Docker-compose-stack-file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
   myApp-back-apache:
    image: localhost:5000/apache
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: myApp-back
        target: /var/www
     
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      HTTPD_FPM_HOST: myApp-back-fpm
      HTTPD_FPM_PORT: 9000

  myApp-back-fpm:
    image: php:7.4-fpm
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: myApp-back
        target: /var/www/html
  
  myApp-back-db:
    image: "mariadb:10.6.5"
    environment:  
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
    volumes:
      - myApp-back-db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"

volumes:
  myApp-back-db:
    external: true
```

and My file .env:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3309/db_name?serverVersion=5.7&charset=utf8mb4"
```

Comment: In `docker-compose.yml` file database's name is `root` and in `.env` file db name is `db_name`.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I gave the same no earlier and it's the same. I think it's a mutiple ini file problem but I can't find any other .ini file in the fpm container

Comment: It are extensions  server apach for php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Are you sure you are running `php -m` on the docker container and not your host?(quite common mistake)
2. In your symfony(fpm) docker container `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` resolve to the container itself, not your host machine which has the db exposed on port 3309. Try changing your `DATABASE_URL` to `mysql://root:root@myApp-back-db:3306`.
   Also, you can try setting url to `host.docker.internal` if you are on mac or windows.
3. Create a docker file for fpm and install mysql ext:

docker-composer:

```
myApp-back-fpm:
    build:
        context: .
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: myApp-back
        target: /var/www/html
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql;
```

Comment: I have already tried this but I still have the same problem, I also connected directly to the fpm container to launch doctrine:create but I have the same problem.


I also have this message in addition to the driver problem: 

2022-04-09T15:29:03+00:00 [info] Deprecated user: "PDO::exec()" method could add "int|false" as native return type declaration in future. Do the same in the "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection" child class now to avoid errors or add an explicit @return annotation to remove this message.

Comment: Have you ran `php -m` in `docker-compose exec myApp-back-fpm /bin/sh`? The error message you have posted now is not the same as before and as far as I can tell is not a fatal error

Comment: I get this :

root@f3692a82ba4b:~# php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib

[Zend Modules]

Comment: So you don't have pdo_mysql installed on you fpm container. post the Dockerfile for your fpm container so we can help

Comment: my fpm container is based on the php:7.4-fpm image so I don't use dockerFile:

myApp-back-fpm:
    image: php:7.4-fpm
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: myApp-back
        target: /var/www/html

Comment: however I have activated the extension : /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development

Comment: Yep missed that, can you use the dockerfile I posted in my answer ?